# Is there any way to get a "type" of text from dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

In our chatbot we have a fallback intent but it would be great if I could know if the user was

1. asking a question
2. just saying arbitrary things like "cool", "ok", "got it"
3. complaining (derogatory texts)

I think (3) can be achieved with sentiment analysis, but is there a tool or an additional API that can guess this sort level of categorisation.

These are chat texts so they are super short.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your second option by activating **smallTalk** in Dialogflow. This is specially design and pre-built trained agent to handle such query 'hello, cool' okay, got it, etc.

For the first option asking a question. I am not sure, but before providing an open-end to the user (basically a broad category of the question) I would suggest narrowing down the scope and category with some option and then create an intent for a feature (less open-end scope of conversation the more effective it will be)